# email contact form is not working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I was wondering if someone could see what I am doing wrong here. My html looks like this

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="inputLeft">
            <p>
                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]]" name="name" type="text" id="name" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input class="validate[required,custom[email],length[0,100]]" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input class="validate[required,length[5,600]" name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value="">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="inputRight">
            <p>
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <input name="country" type="text" id="country" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input name="Phone" type="text" id="phone" value="">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="url">Website</label>
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" value="">
            </p>
        </div>
        <p>
            <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="120" rows="8" id="message"></textarea>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

and the php like this

```
<?php
   # recipient
   $recipient = 'sean@seankonig.co.za'

   # subject
   $subject = $_Post['subject'];

   # headers
   $headers = "Website enquiry <>\r\n";

   # message
   $message =  "Name : {$_POST['name']}\n";
   $message .= "Email : {$_POST['email']}\n";
   $message .= "Subject : {$_POST['subject']}\n";
   $message .= "Message : {$_POST['message']}\n";

   if( mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers) ) echo "Mail Sent";
   else echo "Mail Could Not Be Send";
?>
```

When testing it says that the mail has been sent but nothing delivers. Could you please have a look and let me know?

Comment: Is this script executed on a server with an email service running on it ?

Comment: If you are testing this on localhost you need to enable the email service and Check the SPAM folder

Answer (score 0):

With a quick look to your code i found a couple of errors that might cause email to not work

```
$recipient = 'sean@seankonig.co.za'; //you are missing a semicolon here

$subject = $_Post['subject'];//$_POST is not the same as $_Post
```

Comment: Also the header should be `$headers = "From: Website enquiry <email@example.com>\r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

You could also expand your `headers`. This doesn't necessarily effect your content, but it can effect whether your mail enters someone spambox or not:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "FROM: Website.com <noreply@website.com>" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Return-Path: noreply@website.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: noreply@website.com" . PHP_EOL;
```

Please note that `PHP_EOL` may also be written as `\r\n`, but for my scripts `PHP_EOL` works better (headers were shown as content in sent mails).